# How do prevent my site from creating multiple copies of my index page?

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress site is creating dozens of copies of my index page in a folder it calls /page/, so I've got example.com/page/1/, example.com/page/2/, ...example.com/page/49/ all the same as my index page.

I tried the following, but it only redirects the root and not all the pages within the folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)   / [R=301,L]
```

How do I stop this from happening or redirect the entire contents of the folder? I am not a php programmer.

Comment: Is it creating a unique index.php in each page folder or copying your home index.php into those folders? What WordPress version and theme are you using?

Comment: How many posts you have on your website ? if you have many posts it could be pagination.